# Laravel eloquent get count on belongsTo id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, count, relationship

I have 2 tables `subscribers` & `subscriber_packages`. I need to fetch the count of currently active packages for the selected `subscriber` via given `subscriber_package / id`.

Tables:

```
# | subscriber_id | package_id | active
---------------------------------------
1 |             1 |          1 | true  
2 |             1 |          2 | true  
3 |             1 |          3 | true  
4 |             1 |          4 | false 
---------------------------------------
```

App\SubscriberPackage.php

```php
class SubscriberPackage extends Model
{
    public function subscriber()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subscriber::class);
    }
    public function package()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Package::class);
    }

    public function _countActivePackages($subscriberPackage)
    {
        return self::where([
            'id'     => $subscriberPackage,
            'status' => \Common::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ])->whereHas('subscriber')->count();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined the relations in your Subscriber and Package models via pivot ?
And please read about the Pivot Models > https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: Yes, the relations are defined in both of the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your subscriber you need to define correctly a HasManyThrough relationship and just add properly a where cause to check the status even in separate method

```
    public function packages()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Package::class, SubscriberPackage::class);
    }

    public function activePackages()
    {
        return $this->packages()
            ->where("subscriber_package.status", "=", "active");
    }
```

After that you can always make a count with it

`$subscriber->activePackages()->count();`

Comment: I am not on my laptop so you may need to adjust the relation declaration or the where cause ..